# Place a div in the center of another div

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I need to place a rectangular `div` in the middle of another rectangular `div` that's inside yet another container `div`. The image inside the innermost `div` has to be centered both horizontally and vertically in relation to the outermost `div`. How do I do that?

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height:320px;">
    <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0;">             
       <img src="">
    </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add more divs as needed but something along the lines of this? http://jsbin.com/qocude/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I should have mentioned that the outermost div is one of two existing columns, so I can't mess with its display property, because it will interfere with the other column.  The col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 is part of the Bootstrap framework, so I'm stuck with keeping it the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#div1{
  border:1px solid;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

#div2{
  border:1px solid;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:25%;
}

#div3{
  border:1px solid;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
      <div id="div3"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure all the divs have width and height set and then use:

```
margin: 25%;
```

On the inner divs

Comment: That would only set horizontal centering.  I need the image centered both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Hi Sam.  Maybe it's easier if you look at the [code](http://jsbin.com/gesohavure/1/edit?html,css,output) together with the CSS?  Note that the IMG elements are actually going to be dynamically generated by javascript, hence only minimum dimensions are specified.